# AngularJS Refresh ng-repeat in other controller

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services

My code is simple. I need to refresh a ng-repeat.

HTML

```
<div class="quick-actions" ng-controller="DashboardController">
<div class="ui accordion segment">
        <div class="ui top attached label active title">
            <?php echo __('My Tasks'); ?>
            <i class="minus icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="active content">
            <div class="ui items" ng-show="myTasks" id="myTasks">
                <!-- Creacion de Items de los Taks -->
                <div class="item" ng-repeat="T in myTasks">
                    <div class="content">
                        <a class="header" href="/angular/#/task/{{ T.Task.id }}">
                            {{ T.Task.name }}
                        </a>
                        <div class="meta">
                            {{ T.Task.due_date | date : 'dd-MMM-yyyy' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra high-priority" ng-if="T.Task.priority == 50">
                            <i class="circle icon"></i>
                            <?php echo __('High'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra medium-priority" ng-if="T.Task.priority == 25">
                            <i class="circle icon"></i>
                            <?php echo __('Medium'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="extra low-priority" ng-if="T.Task.priority == 0">
                            <i class="circle icon"></i>
                            <?php echo __('Low'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Termina Creacion de los Items -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When income is well DashboardController in angularjs load ng-repeat. Data is correct here.

```
.controller('DashboardController', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams, $q, $timeout, $http, $sce, $location, Sesion, Dashboard, Fullscreen) {

    Dashboard.get_all_tasks().then(function (response) {
        $scope.myTasks = response;
    });

})
```

What I need is that when I'm in another controller I can update this ng-repeat. It does not work (data incorrect) here.

```
.controller('NewTaskController', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams, $q, $timeout, $http, $sce, Sesion, Users, Opportunities, Dashboard) {

Dashboard.get_all_tasks().then(function (response) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.myTasks = response;
                        });
                    });
                });

})
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update the data from another function in the same controller? $scope is contained within a controller. To go between controllers you need to pass data to and from an angular service.

Comment: The reason is because i need to change the view

Comment: I need add more Tasks in NewTaskController but the list it is the same in the all views

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a service to pass data between controllers. Here is a simplified example. It is in this plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tNpnOjvenE7IDQbalvUS?p=info) to play with.

```
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);
projectModule.factory('Service', function() {  
    return {
        thing : {
            x : 100
        }
    };
});
function FirstCtrl($scope, Service) {
    $scope.thing = Service.thing;
    $scope.name = "First Controller";
}
function SecondCtrl($scope, Service) {  
    $scope.foo = Service.thing; 
    $scope.name = "Second Controller!";
}
```

In this way `$scope.thing` from the first controller is linked to `scope.foo` in the second controller via the service using `thing`
You will need to define the structure of `myTasks` in the service you define so that all the elements gets passed correctly. 
Try implementing this into your project and if you have a specific hangup comment here and we will help but I don't know all your code or structure of `myTasks` so I'm not giving copy/paste code.

Comment: Excellent! but I need the ng-repeat is updated while I'm in NewTaskController    :(

Comment: If you are running the two tasks on the same page the data will be bound between them. So you want to create a `Service.myTasks` and then bind that in your controllers to `$scope.myTasks`